# OG description set but Facebook doesn't display it

Tags: facebook, share

The og tags on my site seem to be generating correctly and the Object Debugger indicates that all the properties are set as they should be.

However, if I click the Share button on this page: http://burmacampaign.org.uk/donate/donate-now/ the Facebook Share dialog only displays the og: image, not the description.

Same problem here: http://burmacampaign.org.uk/take-action/free-political-prisoners/no-political-prisoner-left-behind/action-free-zaw-pe/

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The url you are tried to share is http://burmacampaign.org.uk/donate/donate-now/donate-now which if you debug it doesn't have description.

Change your share button to:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://burmacampaign.org.uk/donate/donate-now/" data-type="button"></div>
```

And it should work